# Open select element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to open a `select` element using jQuery? Either that or prevent it from closing when an element is selected. What I want to do is to add subelements in the option list when clicking specific options. This have to work like this:

Select some category ->
If any subcategory exists add these to the original select (easy enough) but this has to be done without closing the select drop-down box.

Is this possible or do I have to figure some other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whi don't you use optgroup?

```
<select id="food" name="food">
  <optgroup label="Fruits">
    <option value="1">Apples</option>
    <option value="3">Bananas</option>
    <option value="4">Peaches</option>
    <option value="5">...</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Vegetables">
    <option value="2">Carrots</option>
    <option value="6">Cucumbers</option>
   <option value="7">...</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Baked Goods">
   <option value="8">Apple Pie</option>
   <option value="9">Chocolate Cake</option>
   <option value="10">...</option>
 </optgroup>
```

Fiddle here (to see how it looks): http://jsfiddle.net/rn39c/

I think this might be what you are looking for because the categories are just label and the sub-categories are the option (with a value that is posted to the server)

EDIT - Then you could add some jQuery to thew mix (this is very basic but it works: you could try to improve it):

```
$('#food option').hide();

$('optgroup').hover(function(){
   $(this).children('option').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).children('option').hide();
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rn39c/1/

Comment: Because I have 10 top categories, most of them with 10 sub categories - I don't want to display close to 100 categories to my users if it isn't necessary...

Comment: The fiddle works great in ff, but there is something wrong in chrome :s

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way you can do this with jQuery however by setting the select list to allow multiple selected options, you automatically end up with something that matched your criteria:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
```

**UPDATE**

If you need the select to be as standard at some times and showing all options at others, you may consider adding and removing the `multiple` attribute according to your needs.

Here's a quck demo of a one way change: http://jsfiddle.net/bGJAw/

Comment: Sort of - this skips the drop-down completely. I want the drop-down to be there but it has to be dynamic..

Comment: You could always attach and detach the multiple attribute using Javascript.

Comment: I think it'd be easier then to just skip the `select` completely and use some sort of `<div>` or whatever to display some css manipulated `radio` buttons to select in stead..

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing the select element is an internal action that you cannot manipulate via JS. You could use select tag with size=5 etc to have it constantly visible, or maybe manipulate the size attribute via JS when the user selects something to make it "stay open", and later set it back to 1, when the user has ended interaction.

Comment: If changing the size on click to a larger number than 1 does not have the desired effect, you have no other choice, but to create a pseduo-element. What I mean is that you have to write a widget that creates an overlaying div that has the selectable items listed and acts like a select element, but you have more control over it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you are looking can be done, but you could also try having 2 select elements.
The first will contain your categories, the second will be populated dynamically depending on the categery selected.